# Ignoring characters in a file while parsing

Tags: c, string, parsing, gcc

i need to parse through a text file and process the data. the valid data is usually denoted by either a timestamp with TS followed by 10 numbers (TS1040501134) or values with a alpabet followed by nine numbers (A098098098)...so it will be like `TS1040501134A111111111B222222222...........TS1020304050A000000000........`

However, there are cases when there will be filler 0s when there is no data. So, such a case might be

```
00000000000000000000TS1040501134A111111111B2222222220000000000TS1020304050A000000000........`
```

Now as we can see I need to ignore these zeros. how might i do this? I am using gnu C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first attempt at something 'C' like in
about 20 years... So what follows is, at best, pseudo-code!

Read in a line of text, then...

```
char timestamp[11]; timestamp[10] = '\0';    
char number[10]; number[9] = '\0';    

for (i = 0 ; i < strlen(text); ) {
  if isAlpha(text[i]) {
     if text[i] == 'T' & text[i+1] == 'S' {
        memcpy(timestamp, text[i+2], 10)
        /* do whatever you do with a timestamp */
        i += 12 /* Skip over timestamp */
     } else {
        memcpy(number, text[i+1], 9)
        /* do whatever you do with a number */
        i += 10 /* Skip over number */
     }
   } else {
     if text[i] != '0' {
        /* handle the error - should not get here */
     }
     i++  /* move to next character */
   }
```

If lines do not have to contain complete strings (eg. one line ends with `TS10405` and
the next line begins with `01134`), you will have to write extra code to manage refreshing the `text` buffer properly.

Comment: @WhirlWind. And you would suggest using... Critisim is welcome, but at least be constructive (instructive) about it.

Comment: strnlen(); always use the length-limited variants of the string functions.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to read the file into a string, then use strnstr() to locate the "TS" substring in it.  The string strnstr() returns will be the start of your time stamp.

To find the next timestamp, start strnstr on the same buffer at a pointer after the string you just found.  If dealing with multiple strings, you'll have to deal with the situation where a single timestamp is split across multiple strings.